# Split an array only every third time, when the split char appears

Tags: c#, split

I hava a php file on my server that sends the information in a string like this to my app(c#):

Text|Name|Date|Text|Name|Date|Text|Name|Date|......now I want to split it so, that I can fill a ListViewerItem with Text, Name and Date, the next combination of this three(Text, Name, Date) should go in a new ListViewerItem. 
How can I split the string only every third time at "|" ?

Comment: Why not use JSON ([PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php) [C#](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx)) - will make your life easier..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just split on the pipe symbol and loop with a take of 3:

```
public void Foo(string content)
{
    var entries = content.Split('|');

    for(int i = 0; i < entries.Length; i += 3)
    {
        var text = entries[0 + i];
        var name = entries[1 + i];
        var date = entries[2 + i];

        // TODO: add values to listview.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Split the string, then group the strings:

```
string[] values = data.Split('|');
List<string[]> lines =
  Enumerable.Range(0, values.Length / 3)
  .Select(
    i => new string[] { values[i * 3], values[i * 3 + 1], values[i * 3 + 2] }
  )
  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming Text, Name, Date are actually values so the only common separator is the |. I think the best way would be to split the string on | and then loop the resulting array. Keep a counter and at every third item create an object with properties Text, Name and Date. This object is then added to a list which is then bound to the ListViewer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var values = "a|b|c|a|b|c|a|b|c|a|b|c|a|b|c|a|b|c|a|b|c|a|b|c".Split('|');
var result = Enumerable.Range(0, values.Length).GroupBy(i => Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor((i / 3d)))).Select(group => String.Join("|", group.Select(i => values[i])));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Regex` and `LINQ`:

```
var result = from Match match 
               in Regex.Matches(inputString, @"((?<t>\w+)\|(?<n>\w+)\|(?<d>\w+))+")
                select
                    new
                        {
                            Text = match.Groups["t"].Value,
                            Name = match.Groups["n"].Value,
                            Date = match.Groups["d"].Value
                        };
```